# How to emit once the observable data variable is not NULL

Tags: rxjs, nuxt.js

I'm new to RxJS, and I'm trying to figure out how to observe the data when it become available. I'm using Nuxt SSR and I'm fetching data from Firebase. The initial `post` value is set to `null`, and once the data object become available, it should run the `head()` function only once. I get this type error.

```
Cannot read property 'pipe' of null
```

If I initiate `post: {},` as empty object, I get this type error.

```
post$.pipe is not a function
```

Appreciate if I can get some help or guidance.

```js
// page\:post.vue
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'
export default {
  fetch() {
    this.fetchPost()
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('posts', ['post']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('posts', ['fetchPost']),
  },
  head() {
    const post$ = this.post

    post$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((post) => {
      return {
        title: this.post.title,
        link: [{ rel: 'canonical', href: this.post.canonical }],
        meta: [
          { hid: 'name', itemprop: 'name', content: this.post.title },
          {
            hid: 'description',
            itemprop: 'description',
            content: this.post.content,
          },
        ],
      }
    })
  },
}
</script>

// store\posts.js
export const state = () => ({
  post: null,
})
export const mutations = {
  setPost(state, payload) {
    state.post = payload
  },
}
export const actions = {
  async fetchPost({ commit }, key) {
    const doc = await postsCollection.doc(key).get()
    if (doc.exists) commit('setPost', doc.dat())
  },
}
```

### **Edit**

Using `Subject`. However, there is still issue where the meta tags are generated before the post data is set.

```js
// page\:post.vue
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'
export default {
  fetch() {
    this.fetchPost()
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('posts', ['post']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('posts', ['fetchPost']),
  },
  head() {
    const postSubject = new Subject()
    const post = postSubject.asObservable()

    postSubject.next(this.post)

    post.subscribe((post) => {
      return {
        title: post.title,
        link: [{ rel: 'canonical', href: post.canonical }],
        meta: [
          { hid: 'name', itemprop: 'name', content: post.title },
          {
            hid: 'description',
            itemprop: 'description',
            content: post.content,
          },
        ],
      }
    })
  },
}
</script>

// store\posts.js
export const state = () => ({
  post: null,
})
export const mutations = {
  setPost(state, payload) {
    state.post = payload
  },
}
export const actions = {
  async fetchPost({ commit }, key) {
    const doc = await postsCollection.doc(key).get()
    if (doc.exists) commit('setPost', doc.dat())
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to an `Observable`. As I understood, in your case `this.post` is not type of an `Observable`.
As `this.post` is populated at some point of time, you need to `subscribe` to an `observable` which should emit data when you say `this.post` is now populated with data. For that you can use a [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject).

See this example: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nbwjsv?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts)

Comment: I've updated my question with using the `Subject`, however, the code returned early before `this.post` is set. Can you help to to see if I have done anything wrong?

Comment: where do you set value for `this.post`. is it in `setPost(state, payload) {
    state.post = payload
  }` ? If so you have to `postSubject.next(payload)` there. 

I can't edit your code block as I don't know how to run that. Otherwise I could have changed that.

Comment: Here I created a sample [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gekgbn?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts). It's currently having error as the variables are not defined before the data is set.

Comment: see this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-aqbpdk?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts). go through the inline comments